# Multi-version build with SBT

Tags: sbt

I want to implement the following build in SBT:

- Having multiple scala version
- Having multiple target version (because of a library dependency)

Let's take for example an external Lib, that exist in version 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, and Scala 2.92, 2.10.2, I would like to compile, assembly and publish:

- MyProject_externalLib1.0_scala_2.9.2
- MyProject_externalLib1.0_scala_2.10.2
- MyProject_externalLib2.0_scala_2.9.2
- MyProject_externalLib2.0_scala_2.10.2
- MyProject_externalLib3.0_scala_2.9.2
- MyProject_externalLib3.0_scala_2.10.2

By default, however, I would want to work in a single version. Only when I launch a release processes, all the versions should be compiled and tested and assembled.

Is there a simple way to implement this multiple-version build in Sbt?

Comment: is `externalLib` itself a scala library that is cross-published against 2.9.2 and 2.10.2? or is it a simple java library?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### cross building

Having multiple Scala version in sbt is fairly common, and it's called cross building or cross publishing. See sbt's [Cross-building page](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.4/docs/Detailed-Topics/Cross-Build.html) for details. All you have to do is:

```
scalaVersion := "2.10.2"

crossScalaVersions := Seq("2.10.2", "2.9.2")
```

By sbt's naming convention, your published artifact will have binary version post fix, which is `_2.10` for Scala 2.10.x, and `_2.9.2` for Scala 2.9.2. This is to take advantage of the binary compatibility among the 2.10 series. You can use `crossVersion` to control that aspect.

### cross building against an external library

Cross building against an external library is a bit more tricky. The closet situation I can think of is [a plugin for Dispatch](https://github.com/eed3si9n/repatch-twitter/blob/93d4fae43311b86036c6aaad76f5af0f101b98f5/project/build.scala). In there, I created a custom setting called `dispatchVersion`:

```
lazy val dispatchVersion = SettingKey[String]("x-dispatch-version")
```

This is set in the `buildSettings` as

```
dispatchVersion := "0.10.1"
```

and my version prefixed with `dispatch0.10.0_`:

```
version <<= dispatchVersion { dv => "dispatch" + dv + "_0.1.0" }
```

Here's how to add dependencies using the key:

```
libraryDependencies <++= (dispatchVersion) { (dv) => Seq(
  "net.databinder.dispatch" %% "dispatch-core" % dv,
  "net.databinder.dispatch" %% "dispatch-json4s-native" % dv
)}
```

For Java libraries it should be `%` instead of `%%`:

```
libraryDependencies <++= (externalLibVersion) { (el) => Seq(
  "org.apache" % "foo" % el,
  "org.apache" % "foo-extention" % el
)}
```

Aside from making a custom plugin like [sbt-cross-building](https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-cross-building), there's no easy way to iterate over a sequence of external versions. You can write a shell script like:

```
sbt "set externalLibVersion := \"1.0\"" +assembly "set externalLibVersion := \"2.0\"" +assembly "set externalLibVersion := \"3.0\"" +assembly
```

Comment: is there any way to set the different sbt versions for the different subprojects?

Comment: @Alex You should open a separate question instead of asking me in a comment.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20825539/specify-different-version-of-sbt-for-a-subproject-in-multi-project