# How to resolve libraryDependencies after sbt version upgrade to sbt 1.0

Tags: scala, sbt

Hi my question refers to an old thread :
[Multi-version build with SBT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18374362/multi-version-build-with-sbt/48380331#48380331)

This is exactly how the library dependencies are mentioned in my project as well

```
libraryDependencies <++= (dispatchVersion) { (dv) => Seq(
  "net.databinder.dispatch" %% "dispatch-core" % dv,
  "net.databinder.dispatch" %% "dispatch-json4s-native" % dv
)}
```

but we have upgraded to sbt 1.0 which doesnt support this sort of library add. I've tried to import the scala file that contains the variable for eg. "dispatchVersion" which is of type settingKey[Map[symbol, String]] consists of all the latest version numbers similar to what you've mentioned.

How do i migrate the libraryDependencies similar to something mentioned above, as per the sbt version 1.0.0 syntax?
The error that i'm getting is as below:

```
 error: No implicit for Append.Values[Seq[sbt.librarymanagement.ModuleID], sbt.Def.Initialize[Seq[sbt.librarymanagement.ModuleID]]] found,
      so sbt.Def.Initialize[Seq[sbt.librarymanagement.ModuleID]] cannot be appended to Seq[sbt.librarymanagement.ModuleID]
    libraryDependencies ++= dispatchVersion { v => Seq(
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "net.databinder.dispatch" %% "dispatch-core"          % dispatchVersion.value,
  "net.databinder.dispatch" %% "dispatch-json4s-native" % dispatchVersion.value,
)
```

Comment: Thanks @Dale, the dispatchversion was just an example. Actually i want to import values for spark-core, spark-avro,spark-sql in the libraryDependencies, the version numbers of which are defined in the variable dispatchVersion(of type settingKey[Map[symbol,String]]), for example like,  dispatchVersion :=Map('sparkCore->"2.0.0",'sparkAvro->"1.8" ) so on and so forth. So what i'm trying to achieve is dispatchVersion.sparkCore, dispatchVersion.sparksql in the build.sbt. How do i do that? I hope the explanation was not confusing

Comment: `dispatchVersion.value('sparkCore)`, `dispatchVersion.value('sparkAvro)`.

Comment: I tried this yesterday and it worked, thought i'd update it today, but thanks a lot @Dale for the answer this is what i was looking for.